# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with .append() string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error in the `$('#savetickets-list')` line. I want to dynamically add fields to a table, the table has the id in HTML.

```
<div class="savetickets-list">
</div>
```

In javascript I fill the table in a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // the data comes from a web database
    var ticketname = results.rows.item(i).iTicketName;

    $('#savetickets-list').append('
        <div class="saveticket gradient-top">
            <h3>' + ticketname + '</h3>
        </div>
    ');
}
```

I dont know how to solve this. jQuery is loaded, I also checked the name of the selector.

Please help.

Comment: What is the value of `ticketname`? Can you post the contents of `results.rows` in your question.

Comment: This looks for an `id`: `$('#savetickets-list')`, while you have `class="savetickets-list"` in your markup.

Comment: I have edited the title so it's more obvious that the code doesn't even run in the first place (**Syntax** Error, cmon people..)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: It also didnt work withouth the "ticketname" in the .append('..content..') content. So I think it´s ok if I save the work of posting it, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#savetickets-list').append('\
        <div class="saveticket gradient-top">\
            <h3>' + ticketname + '</h3>\
        </div>\
    ');
```

when you want to write multiline strings in JS, you must escape new lines.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are using new lines.

JS does not automatically read new lines for you. It treats them as new statements.

The way I prefer to do this is like:

```
$('#savetickets-list').append('<div class="saveticket gradient-top">'+
    '<h3>' + ticketname + '</h3>'+
'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked.
The problem is in the newlines, you have to **concatenate** strings or put all the statement in a single line.